# will buying a new dell vostro 3500 keyboard work on all dell vostor 3500 devices

Tags: keyboard, dell-vostro

I have dell vostro 3500 black color, and many keys are not wroking after i drop a cup of cofee on it.so i check online web sites and i found many keyboards for dell vostro 3500. and i check one keyboard and its keys looks 100% the same as mine . so can i buy it online and be confident that it will work on my laptop, or there might be inconpatibility ? and what other things i need to check to make sureit will work well on my laptop? can the cable position differ for example?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely yes.  Parts within the same make and model number are almost always interchangeable.  There are some rare exceptions, but they dont come up often.  However if this is a 3rd party replacement, you never know what you are going to get.  Be sure to buy from a place with a good reputation and return policy.

Comment: it is mentioned that the sheller is dell itself.

Comment: but i have note something.when i removed the keyboard from my laptop the model number is NSK-DJ F01. while on the online website the model number is Model Numbers: NSK-DJ301 . so does this make any problem ?